# How to change color scheme for static methods in IntelliJ IDEA / Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

How to disable italics on static methods called inside AndroidStudio IDE?

[image]

I know, it's a personal preference question but is there a way to disable italics? and only keep the colour coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Settings/Preferences (on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Java | Methods | Static method`

[image]

**Additional trick**: to easily find the corresponding color scheme settings do the following:

- Put the cursor at the needed element you need to change
- Press `Shift` twice
- Type `Just to Colors and Fonts` and press Enter. Then select the corresponding option